# Документировать функции по генерации шаблонов

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, компиляция, документация

Добрый день! 
Задача заключается в следующем: есть интерфейс (например, ITemplateGenerator) и от него наследуются классы. В каждом из этих классов реализованы свои методы и есть описание этих методов (реализовано при помощи тегов  и т.п.). Нужно собрать документацию именно по этим функциям в html или doc.
Нашла инфу, что при компиляции решения формируются XML-ки и из них можно вытянуть инфу. Но дело в том, что решение очень большое и эти классы раскиданы в разных местах и как их всех найти, очень проблематично.

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста в ваш вопрос пример кода.

Comment: Не совсем понял суть вопроса. Вам необходимо найти и собрать в html все файлы xml документации?

Comment: А doxygen вам не поможет? И что компилятор xml генерирует, бывает такое?

Comment: Вот именно, что не все файлы xml документации, а только те, в которых содержится информация о методах классов, наследованных от одного интерфейса. К сожалению, код предоставить не могу

Comment: с doxygen я не работала, в место него использовала sandcastle. Эта утилитка генерировала справку по всему проекту и к тому же у нее были проблемы с выводом русскоязычных функций. И да, в настройках можно включить генерацию xml

Comment: Можно попробовать рефлексией пройтись по сборкам проекта, найти все классы, реализующие этот интерфейс. Потом из xml-документации вытянуть нужную инфу. Сложновато, но не знаю, как иначе.